# Grails plugin version incompatibility warning

Tags: grails, groovy, semantic-versioning

as per [Grails official documentation](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.0/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins), if I define the following grailsVersion on a plugin

```
def grailsVersion = "3.3.10 > *"
```

This means that the grails app on which this plugin is installed should be at least 3.3.10.

I acknowledged this based on this statement on the same official doc:

> grailsVersion - The version range of Grails that the plugin supports.
>   eg. "1.2 > *" (indicating 1.2 or higher)

But then I'm not able to understand the following log

```
2019-10-22 15:11:16.834 +0200 WARN  (ain) [ins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager] Plugin [myplugin:0.1.0-rc3] may not be compatible with this application as the application Grails version is less than the plugin requires. Plugin is compatible with Grails version 3.3.10 > * but app is 4.0.0
```

Other strange thing is that if I use

```
def grailsVersion = "3.0.0 > *"
```

Then no warnings are there... Which is inline with grails doc.

So either I'm misunderstanding or something weird is happening whe using grailsVersion=3.3.10

Comment: Are you doing this through an IDE? Perhaps your IDE installed version and your local version of Grails are different. Trying doing a 'grails -version' from the shell and your IDE console. and see if they are the same

Comment: I ran the above from the console itself. @erichelgeson got the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is when `DefaultGrailsPluginManager` is converting the grails version in a very simple way and in this case is failing - the grailsVersion is converted to `3310` and `400` (stripping the .'s) - 400 < 3310

It also explains why 3.0.0 works (3.3.0 -> 300). 400 > 300

You can see the logic here 
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/plugins/DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java#L378

And the string to version number here - https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/plugins/DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java#L421

I would open an issue on grails-core with the details or even better open a PR to fix.

Comment: I will try to patch this with a PR! Thanks a lot for this precious hint !